# Examples of Unitary Matrices with coefficients all having the same amplitude

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am looking for examples of unitary matrices like this one
$$A = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left( \begin{array}{rr} 1 & 1 \\ 1 &-1 \end{array} \right)$$
where each coefficient has the same amplitude, here $1/\sqrt{2}$.
This example has real coefficients but each coefficient could have a phase $e^{i\phi}$.
In two dimensions more generally
$$B = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left( \begin{array}{rr} 1 & e^{ia} 
\\ -e^{i(c-a)} & e^{ic} \end{array} \right)$$

In 4 dimensions an example is
$$ A \otimes A = \frac{1}{2}\left( \begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
1 & -1 & 1 & -1 \\
1 & 1 & -1 & -1 \\
1 & -1 & -1 & 1 
 \end{array} \right)$$

I am having difficulty finding a 3 dimensional example.
I tried this
$$ \left( \begin{array}{ll} 
1      & \alpha & \alpha^2 \\ 
\alpha & \alpha^2 & 1 \\
\alpha^2 & 1 & \alpha \\
\end{array}  \right) $$
with $\alpha = e^{2\pi i/3}$ but it does not seem to be unitary.
I am interested because these examples would help with entropy computations with "mutually unbiased" variables.

[Hadamard matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_matrix) are also examples

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_Hadamard_matrix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The matrix
$$
A = \frac{1}{\sqrt 3}
\left( \begin{array}{ll} 
1      & 1 & 1 \\ 
1 & \alpha & \alpha^2 \\
1 & \alpha^2 & \alpha \\
\end{array}  \right)
$$
is unitary.  This is an instance of the more general [Fourier Matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFT_matrix), which answers your question for unitary matrices of arbitrary size.  Note that these matrices are unitary and are symmetric, but not generally Hermitian.